# Framework7 Autocomplete doesn't work (

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, html-framework-7

I just need to understand how it works. I need the basic code like js, html. I want to understand if i need to initialize the T7 in myApp.js or it has been already done by autocomplete initialization code? Appreciate any help from you guys!

Comment: F7 initialization is must to run the app, Without f7 init DOM events will not work,After f7 init you need to initialize autocomplete as well,But it depends on what type of autocomplete you use,There are multiple types of autocomplete in f7, Hope this helps

Comment: It is already there in framework7.js file. If you include that file in your html page, no need to intialize, otherwiese need to intialize.